# max(id) and limit 10, but use them in different places

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, limit, fetch

I have two tables, posts and sections.  I want to get the last 10 posts WHERE section = 1,
but use the 10 results in different places.  I make a function:

```
     function sectionposts($section_id){
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
$maxpost1 ="SELECT max(id) from posts WHERE section_id = $section_id ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 20";
$maxpost12 =mysql_query($maxpost1);
while ($maxpost_rows = mysql_fetch_array($maxpost12 ,MYSQL_BOTH)){
$maxpost2 = $maxpost_rows[0];
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = $maxpost2";
$query2 = mysql_query($query);
return $query2;
}
$query2 = sectionposts(6);
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query2)){
echo $rows['title'] . "<br/>" . "<br/>";
echo $rows['id'] . "<br/>" . "<br/>";
echo $rows['image_section'] . "<br/>";
echo $rows['subject'] . "<br/>";
echo $rows['image_post'] . "<br/>";
}
```

How can it take these ten results but use them in different places, and keep them arranged from one to ten.

this was the old case and i solve it but i found another problem, that, if the client had deleted a post as id = 800 "so there aren't id = 800 in DB" so when i get the max id minus $NUM from it, and this operation must be equal id = 800, so i have a programing mistake here, how can i take care of something like that.

```
    function getmax_id_with_minus ($minus){
    mysql_set_charset('utf8');
    $maxid ="SELECT max(id) FROM posts";
    $maxid1 =mysql_query($maxid);
        while ($maxid_row = mysql_fetch_array($maxid1)){
                $maxid_id = $maxid_row['0'];
                $maxid_minus = $maxid_id - $minus;
                }
    $selectedpost1 = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = $maxid_minus";
    $query_selectedpost =mysql_query($selectedpost1);
        return ($query_selectedpost);

}
<?php 
$ss = getmax_id_with_minus (8);
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($ss)){
$main_post_1 = $rows;
?>
```

anyway "really" thanks again :) !

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_query`?

Comment: You've got some cargo-cult programming. Your max() query can only ever return a single row, since you're not using a group-by clause. Therefore your while() loop to fetch the results is pointless. As well, the code is racy - another record could be inserted into the db between the time you do the max() query and then fetch the actual max record. Ditto on the while loop for displaying the results - unless you've got multiple duplicate IDs occuring, you'd only get a single row, making the while() loop pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few thoughts regarding posted code:

- First and foremost, you should stop using `mysql_` functions as they are being [deprecated](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql) and are vulnerable to SQL injection.

> ```
> $maxpost1 ="SELECT max(id) from posts WHERE section_id = $section_id ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 20";
> ```

- When you `SELECT` `MAX`, `MIN`, `COUNT`, `AVG` ... functions that only return a single row, you do not need an `ORDER BY` or a `LIMIT`.
- Given that you are only asking for the `MAX(id)`, you can save work by combining your queries like so:

> ```
> SELECT * FROM posts 
> WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) from posts WHERE section_id = $section_id)
> ```

If I'm understanding what you're trying to do (please correct me if I'm wrong), your function would look something like:

```
function sectionposts($section_id) {
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT title, id, image_section, subject, image_post FROM posts " 
        . "WHERE section_id = ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $section_id);
    return mysqli_query($link, $stmt)
}

$result = sectionposts(6);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $rows['title'] . "<br /><br />";
    echo $rows['id'] . "<br /><br />";
    echo $rows['image_section'] . "<br />";
    echo $rows['subject'] . "<br />";
    echo $rows['image_post'] . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to store them in an array.

```
 $posts = array(); //put this before the while loop. 
 $posts[] = $row; //put this in the while loop
```

Comment: um,.. didn't get you good, could you please enplane more :) .

Comment: the function will be like this

    function sectionposts($section_id){
        mysql_set_charset('utf8');
        $posts = array();
        $maxpost1 ="SELECT max(id) from posts WHERE section_id = $section_id ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10";
        $maxpost12 =mysql_query($maxpost1);
         }
        $query2 = sectionposts(6);
        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query2)){
         $posts[] = $rows;
Okay, but how i will get the results ?
    echo $rows['title'];
    echo $rows['id'];
    echo $rows['image_section'];
    echo $rows['subject'];
    echo $rows['image_post'];
thanks michael

Comment: @michael-wheeler I don't believe the OP want's to put the results into an array as they are fetching the result set and using a `while` loop to display it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, to save yourself a lot of pointless code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE section_id=$section_id HAVING bar=MAX(bar);"
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo ...;
echo ...;
```

The `having` clause lets you find the max record in a single operation, without the inherent raciness of your two-query version. And unless you allow multiple records with the same IDs to pollute your tables, removing the while() loops also makes things far more legible.